# How to check if a site user is real (without every time showing him a captcha)?

Tags: security, web, google-analytics, analytics, captcha

I want to count page views and/or users on my site.

How to exclude bot (or otherwise fraudulent) views from the count?

I want to make it highly secure so that it would be very difficult to write a bot that significally tampers the statistics.

My ideas of solutions:

- Use Google Analytics API (does it have such an API?)
- Show captcha before showing the page (very disturning for user experience)

Comment: I also want to make it difficult for others to create sites that would deliver false statistics to my backend server.

Comment: Related question: How does Google AdSense protect itself from fraudulent clicks and fraudulent RPM shows? I just want to do the same.

Comment: If Google AdSense is like the other groups I've worked with (I used to be in anti-counterfeiting, which has similar concerns), they do it by having a team who continually watches for new attacks and regularly adapting their system as old techniques are defeated. Most teams I've dealt with who do this build up a reserve of new techniques that they can deploy as old techniques are defeated. It's a never ending arms-race with no permanent solution. Also, if they're like most organizations I've worked with, they accept a certain level of fraud as the cost of doing business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ReCaptcha serverside and get user 'botness' scored. [Simo Ahava has a great guide](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-google-analytics-bot-detection-with-recaptcha/) on implementing this.